# Integral functional equation

Tags: functional-equations

Some friends and I are having trouble with a functional equation problem :

> If $f : (0,1) \to \mathbb R$ is a positive continuous function satisfying $$\int_t^1 f(x)f\left(\frac{t}{x}\right)dx = \sqrt{t}$$ for all $t$, then $f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2x}{\pi(1-x^2)}}$.

The function is not in $L^2$ or any nice Hilbert / normed space, so functional analysis techniques seem out of reach. I've tried various changes of variables, like $y = x /\sqrt t$ and $y = t/x$, but none of these yielded anything valuable. I've also tried integrating over u, but it didn't do much.

The problem might reduce to proving that two solutions $f,g$ have to be equal almost everywhere / on a dense subset of $(0,1)$, as we've been able to show that the given function is indeed a solution.

Any ideas would be welcome !

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Let $f_0(x) = \sqrt{2x/(\pi-\pi x^2)}$. Two quick ideas: 

1. assume for contradiction $\overline{f}$ is another such function that differs from $f_0$ on a subset of $(0,1)$ of non-zero lebesgue measure. Since the functions are positive, you may be able to combine integrals and get some measure-theoretic contradiction

2. As $f$ is continuous, you may be able to use the first fundamental theorem of calculus. Although, you'd have to deal with $t$ being in the integrand.  Maybe a way around this is to convert to double integrals with the function $g(x,t) = f(x)f(t/x)$ or something similar